# Check if exists records to insert or update In MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, left-join

Every week I need to load 50K~200K rows of records from a raw CSV file to my system.

Currently I am solution is to load the CVS to a temp table(empty it after the process), then run my **Stored procedure** to manipulate the data to different relevant tables in my system. If records already exists will run **update** query (80% records in CSV are already in my system table), if not exists will **Insert** the records.

The problem i am facing now is the tables are growing to few millions records, approx. 5~6 millions each tables. 
"**Select Exist**" seems very slow too, after that i change to **left join tables** by batch also slow.
Even I just loaded 5K records it may took about few hours to finish the Stored Procedure process.

Any good and faster solutions to handle huge records when comparing tables to decide insert/update records?

Thanks!!

Jack

Comment: Start with table indexing. Then you can look at several online articles for managing and scaling large databases.

Comment: I did the indexing before. Currently it starts performs bad when the tables grow to millions rows.

Comment: Have a look at MySQL's "REPLACE INTO" statement, it may be the solution you are looking for : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Yes, Miki, I am thinking to use REPLACE INTO too ;), just not sure the performance is as good as using left join.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following process which will reduce your time

First try to update the record and check the number of rows affected if number of rows affected = 0 then insert record.

But make sure every time you need to modify the modified_Date if modified_Date not exist in table then you need to add that because if the all data are same in new and old record then it will create new query just because there is no modification in table record so it will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Slow responds of MySQL is almost always a problem of wrong indexing or uncorrect use of it.

If you use keys or/and index correct, a INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... should work.

Try to work only on an existing index/key. Check your statements with a EXPLAIN SELECT.

IMHO your tmp-table based preprocessing is ok.